# Changing AWS EMR log location?

Tags: amazon-emr

Is it possible to change the bucket & path of the Log URI of a running EMR cluster?  Or is the only way to change it to terminate & restart the cluster?  We had a typo in the bucket name of a cluster we have already spun up and done some work on, so we'd like to change the log location without terminating the cluster.

Comment: Nope... We're just living with the logs going to a place other than what we wanted...

Comment: no apis added for this??

Comment: @BruceP did you able to find the answer... i'm able to get the system logs in s3 bucket but i have a custom application log which i'm not able to get to bucket folder please tell me if you know how to get that custom log folder to s3 bucket ...thanks in advance ....this site i have referred to get the answer but unable to find..https://www.loggly.com/blog/an-introduction-to-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-emr-logging/

Comment: I think you might find a configuration in logpusher /etc/logpusher/ then grep wrong bucket name